# React Native WebView goBack loses parameters - Android

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I am having an issue with the React Native WebViews goBack/goForward functions working as expected on Android. From a high level, here is the basics of my use case:

1. I have a RN app with a list of components that when tapped open a new screen with a WebView and loads a url passed from the component.
2. The url passed to the WebView has certain parameters appended to it. Those parameters are used by my web server to remove certain items from the web page to be more app friendly, i.e. header, ads, etc..
3. Any subsequent link tapped in the WebView falls into 1 of 2 categories for the most part: A) internal urls to other pages on my website, which require those specific parameters appended to them, and B) external urls to pages other than my website, which are then opened in a native browser or native client via RN Linking.
4. I am using the onNavigationStateChange handler to determine which category the new url (the link a user tapped) is and performs one of the following: A) internal urls are appended with the needed parameters, the WebView is forced to stop loading, then the url with required parameters is used to set the state of the url passed as the source to the WebView. This effectively stops the loading of the url without the parameters, then forces the WebView to re-render with the new url with the parameters. B) external urls force the WebView to stop loading then are opened in a native browser or native client via the RN Linking component.

Side note: the NativeEvent's canGoBack and canGoForward properties are captured in the onNavigationStateChange handler as well and are use to set internal state of screen component, and thereby used to enable the back and forward buttons on my simple WebView navigation toolbar. This seems to work just fine.

The issue, I believe, is not that the parameters are lost, rather the url without the parameters and the url with the parameters are added to the WebView's history stack, at least on Android. I've actually had mixed results, sometimes both urls are added to the history stack, sometimes only one of them. For iOS, the only the destination url with params is added to the history stack and all seems to work as expected.

I have also attempted to use onShouldStartLoadWithRequest handler to halt the loading of urls without the needed parameters, append the parameters, and then set the state with the correct url, but that approach mangles the history stack all together. I have also attempted stop the loading of the WebView and inject JS to redirect the WebView to the proper url, but that also seems to break the history stack.

Does anyone know how to properly intercept a WebView's subsequent url changes and append parameters to the request so that the WebView's history stack is properly preserved?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a couple things to resolve my issues:

1. On Android, if the url did not have the required parameters, I forced the WebView to not load the url from the onShouldStartLoadWithRequest handler by returning false and instead updated the state of the url with the parameters to force a re-render. This alone can cause issues related to the built in WebView history stack and back/forward navigation, so I also ended up...
2. Creating a custom history array of urls and custom navigation management.

The downside to my approach is that the onLoadProgress does not fire on Android
    due to returning false in the onShouldStartLoadWithRequest handler
    (I assume), despite forcing a re-render with the new URL.  So I
    had to add a workaround for my animated page loading progress bar by
    setting a progress value to a small number in the onStartLoad
    callback, and setting the progress value to 1 in the onEndLoad
    callback (which I was anyway).